# How to work around CLion 2017.2 thinking constexpr if's make everything after unreachable

Tags: syntax-highlighting, c++17, clion

I know CLion 2017.2 has very limited support for C++17 features (basically everything other than nested namespaces), but it's especially frustrating that it treats constexpr if's as if everything after is unreachable code until the end of the function.

Anyone know a workaround to at least get some functionality after the constexpr if to the end of the function?

[image]

Comment: You might want to consider filing a bug report under JetBrains tracking system [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com), probably as a (sub-)issue related to [OC-10682](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-10682).

Answer (score 1):

`if constexpr` is c++17 feature, which is not support by CLion yet, so it don't understand what happen in code.

If you bother only with `unreachable code` highlighting you can [disable that inspection completly in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2NBw.png)

Or disable it on [particular code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVGHB.png)

Sadly, there currently is no way to disable wavy red line